# Applying functions data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a following function to calculate a value for two parameter x,y:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def some_func(pt1,pt2):
    return math.sqrt( (pt2[0]-pt1[0])*(pt2[0]-pt1[0]) + (pt2[1]-pt1[1])*(pt2[1]-pt1[1]) )
```

usage:

```
a = 1, 2
b = 4, 5
some_func(a,b)
#outputs = 4.24264
#or some_func((1,2), (4,5)) would give the same output too
```

I have a following df:

```
  seq     x    y    points
    1     2    3    (2,3)
    1    10    5    (10,5)
    1     6    7    (6,7)
    2     8    9    (8,9)
    2    10   11    (10,11)
```

column "points" was obtained using the below piece of code:

```
df["points"] = list(zip(df.loc[:, "x"], df.loc[:, "y"]))
```

I want to apply the some_func function on the whole df, also by grouping them by "seq"

I tried :

```
df["value"] = some_func(df["points"].values, df["points"].shift(1).values)
#without using groupby
```

and

```
df["value"] = df.groupby("seq").points.apply(some_func) #with groupby
```

but both of them shows TypeError saying 1 missing argument or unsupported data type.

Expected df

```
  seq    x    y    points     value
    1     2    3    (2,3)       NaN
    1    10    5    (10,5)     8.24 
    1     6    7    (6,7)      4.47
    2     8    9    (8,9)       NaN
    2     10   11   (10,11)    2.82
```

Comment: I wonder why you import numpy and then you don't use it. I guess you can improve your code by storing your 2d points in np.arrays instead of tuples and compute the distance as np.linalg.norm(pt1 - pt2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) first, but then need replace `NaN`s to tuples - one possible solution is use `fillna`. Last use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
s = pd.Series([(np.nan, np.nan)], index=df.index)
df['shifted'] = df.groupby('seq').points.shift().fillna(s)
df['values'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(x['points'], x['shifted']), axis=1)
print (df)
   seq   x   y    points     shifted    values
0    1   2   3    (2, 3)  (nan, nan)       NaN
1    1  10   5   (10, 5)      (2, 3)  8.246211
2    1   6   7    (6, 7)     (10, 5)  4.472136
3    2   8   9    (8, 9)  (nan, nan)       NaN
4    2  10  11  (10, 11)      (8, 9)  2.828427
```

Another solution is filter out `NaN`s in [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['shifted'] = df.groupby('seq').points.shift()
f = lambda x: some_func(x['points'], x['shifted']) if pd.notnull(x['shifted']) else np.nan
df['values'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
   seq   x   y    points  shifted    values
0    1   2   3    (2, 3)      NaN       NaN
1    1  10   5   (10, 5)   (2, 3)  8.246211
2    1   6   7    (6, 7)  (10, 5)  4.472136
3    2   8   9    (8, 9)      NaN       NaN
4    2  10  11  (10, 11)   (8, 9)  2.828427
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=lambda x,y:some_func(x,y)
f["value"] = f(df["points"].values, df["points"].shift(1).values)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it shows Index Error-   IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.